# Python pandas : groupby on two columns and create new variables

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I have the following dataframe describing the percent of shares held by a type of investor in a company:

```
    company  investor   pct 
       1       A         1
       1       A         2
       1       B         4
       2       A         2
       2       A         4
       2       A         6 
       2       C         10
       2       C         8
```

And I would like to create a new column for each investor type computing the mean of the shares held in each company. I also need to keep the same lenght of the dataset, using transform for instance.

Here is the result I would like to have:

```
     company  investor   pct   pct_mean_A   pct_mean_B   pct_mean_C
       1       A         1        1.5          4            0
       1       A         2        1.5          4            0
       1       B         4        1.5          4            0
       2       A         2        4.0          0            9
       2       A         4        4.0          0            9
       2       A         6        4.0          0            9
       2       C         10       4.0          0            9
       2       C         8        4.0          0            9
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate `mean` and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for helper `DataFrame` which is [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `df`:

```
s = (df.groupby(['company','investor'])['pct']
       .mean()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .add_prefix('pct_mean_'))

df = df.join(s, 'company')
print (df)
   company investor  pct  pct_mean_A  pct_mean_B  pct_mean_C
0        1        A    1         1.5         4.0         0.0
1        1        A    2         1.5         4.0         0.0
2        1        B    4         1.5         4.0         0.0
3        2        A    2         4.0         0.0         9.0
4        2        A    4         4.0         0.0         9.0
5        2        A    6         4.0         0.0         9.0
6        2        C   10         4.0         0.0         9.0
7        2        C    8         4.0         0.0         9.0
```

Or use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with default aggregate function `mean`:

```
s = df.pivot_table(index='company',
                   columns='investor',
                   values='pct', 
                   fill_value=0).add_prefix('pct_mean_')
df = df.join(s, 'company')
print (df)
   company investor  pct  pct_mean_A  pct_mean_B  pct_mean_C
0        1        A    1         1.5           4           0
1        1        A    2         1.5           4           0
2        1        B    4         1.5           4           0
3        2        A    2         4.0           0           9
4        2        A    4         4.0           0           9
5        2        A    6         4.0           0           9
6        2        C   10         4.0           0           9
7        2        C    8         4.0           0           9
```

Comment: OP's dataframe has wrong values for `pct_mean_A`  which is 12.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - Its happen ;)